# Adjust/don't show pro-tempore election notification if there is no election phase

Tags: feature-request, election, global-inbox, beta-sites

[Woodworking Stack Exchange](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/election/1) just had its [first pro-tempore election](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/election/1). Well, not really; there was no election phase since there was only one candidate for one seat. Therefore, the election ended as soon as it started (2019-03-25 20:00 UTC). Still, I received an inbox notification asking me to cast my vote:

[image]

It's great that the system is already smart enough to determine that an election phase is not needed (this wasn't the case before) but it would be nice if the inbox message is either not sent, or somehow altered to a message stating that you would've been able to vote except the election phase is being skipped for this election.

Comment: Indeed the announcement says: "Since this is a pro tempore election, there was no need for it to be competitive. With only one nomination, we skipped the vote." - a short version of that would be a helpful notification. It was [announced on the 7th](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election), and started on the 18th. Everyone? is [Pro Tempore there](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/introducing-the-woodworking-pro-tem-moderators?rq=1). Seems *rigged* if winning is the only outcome, and there's no way to object by voting.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this issue still occurring?

Comment: @V2Blast out of curiosity, what were the last elections for which this could happen? I can check my global inbox whether I got a message or not :)

Comment: @Glorfindel: Looks like the most recent case of an election where we appointed the only candidates who ran was [on Sound Design Stack Exchange last month](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1483/34208).

Comment: @V2Blast hmm ...  I don't remember getting a notification for that, and it's not in my global inbox history, but it's a month ago, so I'm not 100% I didn't get one.

Comment: I'll close this as no longer reproducible; feel free to re-report it if you notice it happening again.